# Number of integer solution to $P(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)=c$ where $P$ is a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

Let $P(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)$ be a homogeneous polynomial with integer coefficients.
Let $C$ be an integer.

Is it true that the equation $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=C$ has only finitely many integer solutions?

**EDIT**: I meant $C$ is positive. Say $C=1$.

Comment: Take $XY = 0$. Conclude.

Comment: Oops! I want $C$ to be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** true without any conditions.

Take for instance $n=2$, and

$$P(X_1)={X_1}+X_2$$

which is homogeneous.

Then the equation $P(X_1,X_2)=0$ has infinitely many integer solutions:

$$(n,-n),\quad n\in \mathbb Z.$$

**Edit.**

Since you want $C>0$, you can take the equation $P(X_1,X_2)=1$, and the solutions are

$$(n,-n+1),\quad n\in \mathbb Z.$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $C$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept when the site lets me in a few minutes. I wonder what nice conditions guarantee that the number of solutions is finite.

Comment: @JoLasker Your question made me wonder what happen if you impose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\in\mathbb N$.